# Replace selected characters in PHP string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, character

I know this question has been asked several times for sure, but I have my problems with regular expressions... So here is the (simple) thing I want to do in PHP:

I want to make a function which replaces unwanted characters of strings. Accepted characters should be: 
a-z A-Z 0-9 _ - + ( ) { } # äöü ÄÖÜ space

I want all other characters to change to a "_". Here is some sample code, but I don't know what to fill in for the ?????:

```
<?php

// sample strings
$string1 = 'abd92 s_öse';
$string2 = 'ab! sd$ls_o';

// Replace unwanted chars in string by _
$string1 = preg_replace(?????, '_', $string1);
$string2 = preg_replace(?????, '_', $string2);

?>
```

Output should be:
$string1: abd92 s_öse (the same)
$string2: ab_ sd_ls_o

I was able to make it work for a-z, 0-9 but it would be nice to allow those additional characters, especially äöü. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow only the exact characters you described:

```
 $str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_+(){}#äöüÄÖÜ -]/", "_", $str);
```

To allow all whitespace, not just the (space) character:

```
 $str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_+(){}#äöüÄÖÜ\s-]/", "_", $str);
```

To allow letters from different alphabets -- not just the specific ones you mentioned, but also things like Russian and Greek, or other types of accent marks:

```
 $str = preg_replace("/[^\w+(){}#\s-]/", "_", $str);
```

If I were you, I'd go with the last one. Not only is it shorter and easier to read, but it's less restrictive, and there's no particular advantage to blocking stuff like `и` if `äöüÄÖÜ` are all fine.

Comment: I'm not sure because I will pass these strings via url of the browser. Allowing even more special characters could cause problems, don't you think?

Comment: @andreas - In that case, consider passing them through **[`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)** if they're part of a querystring. If they're not, `äöüÄÖÜ` are going to give you problems anyway. Normally, `и` and other non-ASCII letters are fine anywhere you can use `äöüÄÖÜ`, because those are non-ASCII as well.

Comment: So, basically, if you can use `äöüÄÖÜ`, you shouldn't have a problem with `и`, `φ`, `ರೃ`, or any other letter from a non-Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-+(){}#äöüÄÖÜ ]` with `_`.

```
$string1 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-+(){}#äöüÄÖÜ ]/', '_', $string1);
```

This replaces any characters except the ones after `^` in the [character set]

**Edit:** escaped the `-` dash.

Comment: The part in the middle, `_-+`, is wrong. That's going to try to find a range between `_` and `+`. You need to move the `-` to the beginning or end of the character class if you want it to be taken literally.

Comment: Hehe thanks, I already wondered why an error came up (warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 13 in /home/www/action.php on line 52)